# SPNEGO in tomcat always prompting password

Tags: java, tomcat, active-directory, kerberos, spnego

My SPNEGO configuration seems to not work and always prompts for a password in my tomcat8.

Installation/Configuration
[SPNEGO install guide](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/spnego_tomcat.html)

I added the library spnego-r9.jar to the "tomcat\lib"-folder.
Added the .conf files as well.
Here the krb5.conf:

```
[libdefaults]
dns_lookup_realm = false
ticket_lifetime = 24h
renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true
rdns = false
default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
udp_preference_limit = 1
default_realm=EXAMPLE.COM
default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc aes256-cts- 
hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac
default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc aes256-cts- 
hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac
permitted_enctypes =  aes256-cts aes128-cts des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc aes256-cts- 
hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac

[realms]
EXAMPLE.COM = {
    default_domain=example.com
    kdc=dc2.example.com:88
}

[domain_realm]
.example.com=EXAMPLE.COM
example.com=EXAMPLE.COM
```

The SpnegoHttpFilter was then added to the web.xml.
Last but not least I contacted our admins and added the following to the user registered in the SpnegoHttpFilter

```
setspn.exe -A HTTP/ourserver01.example.com/projectXY exampleUser
setspn.exe -A HTTP/ourserver01/projectXY exampleUser
```

The result is a password prompt even though my accessing user is logged in to the EXAMPLE.COM domain. To my knowledge this should not happen. I logged on to our server and found, that its domain is a workgoup (using wmic computersystem get domain in cmd) could that be an issue and how would I go and resolve this?

EDIT:
Here the second .conf file:

```
spnego-client {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required;
};

spnego-server {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    storeKey=true
    isInitiator=false;
};
```

Comment: In "SPNego" there is "nego(tiate)". Look at what happens during the negotiation phase, with `curl --trace-ascii wtf.log ...` for instance, then update your question.

Comment: Two configuration files are necessary to use Kerberos authentication: a `jaas.conf` file to tell Tomcat which `LoginModule` to use and a `krb5.conf` file for Kerberos (cf. [Tomcat's authentication](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html)). Can you add the former to the question?

Comment: I added the second file. I am now looking through the different packages being send as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the packages via wireshark and found the unkown pricipalname error.
Thanks for the hint [@Samson Scharfrichter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5162372/samson-scharfrichter)

The correct spn registration is setspn.exe -A HTTP/ourserver01.example.com exampleUser without the project itself.